# LIMIT Result in Progress 10.1C

Tags: sql, limit, progress-4gl, openedge, progress-db

Is there a way to limit the result of a SQL Query in Progress 10.1C like in MYSQL LIMIT 0, 1000?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Progress SQL calls it "TOP" i.e.:

```
SELECT TOP 5 FROM pub.customer ORDER BY balance DESC;
```

Comment: Yes thats good if you want only limit top results but if i want it like from row 1000 to 2000 is that bad! I found it by myself with rowid.